# OrgMode, Is it possible to group options and pass them to LaTeX listings?

Tags: org-mode, latex

I have got an Org buffer like

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{listings}
* How to group ATTR_LATEX options?
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options language=bash,basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,numbersep=3pt,frame=tb
This is a demo of what the listings package produce.
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
echo "hello world"
#+END_SRC
```

Which I can export to LaTeX. However, I would like to group the options passed to the LaTeX listings by defining a macro for the lstlisting environment. For example, I want Org Mode to generate something like :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{BashInputStyle}{
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numbersep=3pt,
    frame=tb
}
\begin{document}
\section{How to group ATTR\(_{\text{LATEX}}\) options?}
This is a demo of what the listings package produce.
\begin{lstlisting}[style=BashInputStyle]
echo "hello world"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I am able to get the `lstdefinesstyle` into the LaTex buffer with:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \lstdefinestyle{BashInputStyle}{language=bash,basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,numbersep=3pt,frame=tb}
```

However, I do not know what do to go get that definitions exported to `\begin{lstlisting}[style=BashInputStyle]`. Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The org manual suggests doing it as follows, passing the options via a `#+ATTR_LATEX:` tag just before the source block.

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{listings}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \lstdefinestyle{BashInputStyle}{language=bash,basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,numbersep=3pt,frame=tb}

* How to group ATTR_LATEX options?

This is a demo of what the listings package produce.
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options style=BashInputStyle
#+BEGIN_SRC bash
echo "hello world"
#+END_SRC
```

[image: Sample output]

Note that org writes out a new `\lstset` before each listing regardless of whether you specify options or not.  This means the above settings apply just to the one given listing.